# Setup (reverse) proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup a proxy that I can use to set it up in my web browser, in the Proxy section.

Not sure but I think what I need is a reverse Proxy.

I'm trying Nginx using `proxy_pass` module, but it redirects to a **specified URL**. What I need to a computer that fast-forward HTTP requests so that the Server see the Proxy computer.

Client <--> Proxy <--> Server

Is Nginx the right approach?

Comment: That's a forward proxy. Nginx is not a good choice for a forward proxy. You should look into other products, e.g. [Squid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_(software))

Comment: @harryPoker Read any article explaining the difference of reverse and forward proxy to understand it better, here is an [example](https://www.linuxbabe.com/it-knowledge/differences-between-forward-proxy-and-reverse-proxy).